# How to rows limit in table and doesnot allow duplicate rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying the form details in table formate in same page. But when i am saving multiple times table rows also increasing, so i want display 3 row only remaining rows will be show in scroll or pagination.

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Message</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" />

<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" />

<label>Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored"></textarea>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;" id="savebutton"><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i> Save </button>
 </form>
```

And for example same mail id displaying second time it doesn't allow.

```
$("button#savebutton").click(function() {
 var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
//---->Form validation goes here
var new_row = '<tr><td class="name">' + name + '</td><td class="email">' + email + '</td><td class="message">' + message + '</td></tr>';
$("table tbody").append(new_row);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem.

1. Disable Save `button` after appending the row.
2. Enable Save `button` when there is change in input/testarea.

Check out working code below.

```js
$("button#savebutton").click(function() {
 var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
//---->Form validation goes here
var new_row = '<tr><td class="name">' + name + '</td><td class="email">' + email + '</td><td class="message">' + message + '</td></tr>';
$("table tbody").append(new_row);

//disable the save button after appending row
$(this).prop("disabled",true);

});

//listen to change in input/textare and then enable the save button
$(document).on('change', 'input, textarea', function() {

  if($("button#savebutton").is(':disabled')){
    $("button#savebutton").prop("disabled",false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Message</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" />

<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" />

<label>Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored"></textarea>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;" id="savebutton"><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i> Save </button>
 </form>
```